# Twisted Websocket - Broadcasting doesn't work when called from another file

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, twisted

I was setting up an Websocket Server which is loggin into another server and pushing data trough the socket to the webpage (trough a subscribe function). As long as i keep calling the broadcast function from the file where the websocket runs, everything is fine. But calling the broadcast method from another python-file where my push-function is printing to command line, no client is recieving a message.

I assume, that calling the broadcast from another file creates another instance and with that the `self.clients` is empty. 
So to sum up, clients connected get the broadcast from `loginGESI()` but not in my second file from `scrptCallbackHandlerExample(subType)`.

Would be happy about any help!

here is my Websocket file:

```
class BroadcastServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onOpen(self):
        self.factory.register(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
        self.factory.unregister(self)

class BroadcastServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
    clients = []

    def __init__(self, url):
        WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, url)

    def register(self, client):
        if client not in self.clients:
            print("registered client {}".format(client.peer))
            self.clients.append(client)

    def unregister(self, client):
        if client in self.clients:
            print("unregistered client {}".format(client.peer))
            self.clients.remove(client)

    @classmethod
    def broadcast(self, msg):
        print("broadcasting message '{}' ..".format(msg))
        print(self.clients)
        for c in self.clients:
            c.sendMessage(msg.encode('utf8'))
            print("message sent to {}".format(c.peer))

def login():
    codesys = Test_Client("FTS_test")
    result = codesys.login()
    # FTS = codesys.searchForPackage("F000012")
    FTS = ["15900"];
    scrptContextId = [None] * len(FTS)
    itemContextIds_array = [None] * len(FTS)
    for i in range(0,len(FTS)):
        result, scrptContextId[i] = codesys.createSubscription(c_ScrptCallbackHandlerExample, 100, int(FTS[i]))
        print("SubscriptionRoomId: "+str(scrptContextId[i]))
        result, itemContextIds_array[i], diagInfo = codesys.attachToSubscription(1, [FTS[i]+'.speed'], [100])
        print("Subscription done for: "+str(itemContextIds_array[i]))
        print("Subscription for: Speed")

    BroadcastServerFactory.broadcast(str(FTS[0]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Logger Websocket
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    # factory initialisieren
    ServerFactory = BroadcastServerFactory
    factory = ServerFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:9000")
    factory.protocol = BroadcastServerProtocol
    listenWS(factory)
    # reactor initialisieren
    webdir = File(".")
    web = Site(webdir)
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, web)

    reactor.callLater(5, login)

    reactor.run()
```

and here my subscription file:

```
# Launch of the CallbackHandler named in the createSubscription function 
# CallbackHandler describes what happens to a variable which changes its value
def scrptCallbackHandlerExample(subType):
    BroadcastServerFactory.broadcast('test')

    # Saves the value of the variables(s) in an array
    dataValue = []
    for i in range(0,subType.size):
        dataValue.append(subType.dataItems[i].node.dataValue)

    # Print variabel informations on the screen
    print "*****Callback - Data Change in a Variable*****"
    print( 'Subscription ID: %d' % subType.subscrId )
    for idx in range(0,subType.size):
        print( '** Item %d **' % idx )
        print( 'Item Id: %d' % subType.dataItems[idx].dataItemId )
        print( 'Item Node ID: %s' % subType.dataItems[idx].node.nodeId )
        print( 'Item data value: %s' % subType.dataItems[idx].node.dataValue )
        print( 'Item data type: %s' % subType.dataItems[idx].node.dataType )
        print( '******************************' )
# Define the type of the function as an eSubscriptionType
CB_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE( None,  eSubscriptionType)
c_ScrptCallbackHandlerExample = CB_FUNC_TYPE( scrptCallbackHandlerExample )
```

Regards

Comment: It doesn't work like that. An other script will run as an other process and has no access to the other process. You need a kind of IPC to do that. https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html

Comment: I was reading in the meantime, too. Couldn't I communicate over global variables? I tried that but it still doesn't work after all.... Another idea was to include the other python file into my socket file but then I get an EOFError 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. And after all I have to admit that I'm pretty new to programming and python at all, an IPC is probably too much for me right now, isn't there a much simpler solution?

Comment: Just to make it more clear: two separate processes with shared code are like two cars with same model of headlights. If you switch on the lights on one, absolutely nothing happens on the other car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, in my oppinion, a pretty neat workaround.

Whenever my subscribe function is called, I connect with a local client to my websocket server and send him a message with the new values, the websocket server then pushes this to the other clients. Since I am still working on it I can't post any code but the functionality is given. So if someone is interested in a solution let me know and I can post mine.